# I want to read from a file which has spaces c++ ifstream

Tags: c++, io, ifstream

My file looks like this

```
0 0 5
1 10 20
2 10 10
3 15 3
4 20 30
5 25 5
```

and I am saving this in a vector. I am not sure how to read it so that I can save each component in a different vector.

Attempt at a solution:

```
if (inFile.is_open()) { 
     while ( inFile) { 
          getline (inFile,line); 
          cout << line << endl; 
     } 
     inFile.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Looks like homework for sure. ;) Edit your question when you have an example of what you've tried.

Comment: What do you mean by "each component"? Do you mean something like "each number (or maybe line?) in an element of a vector? The point of a vector is to store more than one item, so storing each item in a separate vector makes relatively little sense.

Comment: I have tried getline. but it reads the whole line I am not sure how to pick number from a line.

Comment: Yes sorry each number in an element of a vector. 
OK so the number in the each line represent something different. so I have to put them in different vectors so that I can pick number from each vector and then I can process them.
if (inFile.is_open())
    {
      while ( inFile)
        {
          getline (inFile,line);
          cout << line << endl;

        }
      inFile.close();
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
ifstream fin("C:/file.txt");

if(!fin)
{
    cout<<"Cannot Open File";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

vector<vector<int>> v;

int vector_length = 3;

int count = 0;
while(!fin.eof()) //Read till the end of file
{       
    v.push_back(vector<int>()); //Add vector for new line
    int number;
    for(int i=0; i<vector_length; i++)
    {
        fin>>number;  //Read a number from the file
        v[count].push_back(number);  //Add the number to the vector
    }
    count++;
}


//Show the output to confirm that the file has been read correctly
for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<v[i].size(); j++)
    {
        cout<<v[i][j]<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;

}
```